# How to remove blogspot tags in one go?

Tags: tags, blogs, blogger, blogspot

In one of my `blogspot` `blog`, I have written 25 posts with tag `"XYZ"` and `"PQR"`. Now I want to remove tag `"PQR"` from at least 20 posts. I don't want to edit each and every post to remove `"PQR"` tag. How can I achieve my task in a shorter way or in one go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Sign in to blogger

2.Click on you blog name

3.Click on Posts

4.Now filter that tag which you want to remove i.e. `PQR`

5.Now only Posts with `PQR` tag will appear.

6.Now Apply the same label `PQR` to them(the dropdown box from where you create a new label)

Thats it.